# Can I disable ALL notifications on MacOS Ventura by disabling a launchctl service or daemon?

Tags: notifications

MacOS Ventura is buggy concerning the generation of unwanted repetitive notifications. My attempts to suppress them using System Settings have failed. I believe my only alternative is to disable whatever service generates notifications.

Comment: Which notifications? What exact behaviour are you seeing? What makes you think this is the best solution?

Comment: Let me ask my question another way. Can I use launchctl to turn off and disable the notification service or sevices ? If so what is the procedure ?  The system of notifications and focuses is so poorly designed and buggy that I simply want to shut it down and move on.  FYI, there is an article in 9 to 5 Mac today that may help illustrate some of my frustrations